# Sending Push Notification to Desktop application in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets, httpclient

Here is my application scenario...

1. User requests for login and sends credentials to the web server(From Desktop application using httpClient API).
2. Servlet(tomcat) authenticates user and send valid or invalid user information. If user is registered user, servlet will save IP address on the server.
3. Now I have to send some text to the user without getting another request(i.e server push sort of technology). How can I accomplish this functionality and using what technology?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a connection to the server since the other solution requires that you implement a server that runs in the clients and that the clients have public IP addresses.

In chrome you can use [background pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) to keep the connection so that you can close the browser. Use [desktop notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html) from the background page. Other browsers use other techniques. As a fallback you require the page to be open.

Now to the push. My favorite is to use [web sockets](http://www.websocket.org/). But there are several other techniques for this. [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) is a good place to start if you need more info.

If still want to go for the other solution with a server component running at each client. You will have to implement a standalone client. Is this what you want?

Comment: i have studied a bit about commet.. problem with commet is that every where is is used with java script and ajax...but from desktop client side i can not use java script or ajax..if you can give me some hint how to use commet for desktop client side it will be gread.

Comment: You will not have this issue with web sockets. If you need to run java script in a java app you can look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino

Comment: But if you just need to make HTTP requests (which it is all about really) you can use [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/URLConnection.html)

Comment: i am using httpclient classes for making Http requests and it is working quiet will..but i right now i am looking at Rhino..if i am able to run javascript as client side it will be great..!